# Why does my <text input> override the css rules for <fieldset>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my search box to work but the  box is showing on top of my  and the css i gave for my fieldset. it looks like the original text input box is on top of the modified fieldset text box (which i want to use for my wesite). the fieldset box is longer ans perfect but i cannot type into that box because the original small  box is on top of the fieldset css. thank you

index:

```
<form id="search-form" action="/properties/search" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <input type ="text "name="q" placeholder="Search for a Website" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="button" data-hasqtip="5" oldtitle="search" title aria-    describedby="qtip-5">&nbsp;</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

```
css:

#search-form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: left;
}

#search-form fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: 425px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #ced8dd;
}

#search-form input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  font-size: .8125em;
  line-height: 1.3846153846153846;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 5px;
  border-width: 0;
  width: 380px;
}


search-form button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ced8dd;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://images.househappy.org/icon_sprite_1x_v14.png");
  background-position: -10px -22px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I get everything you're saying, but I do see that this `search-form button {` should be `#search-form button {`

Comment: and things like this: `<input type ="text "name...` dude, take 3 seconds more time to type your stuff out neatly, make it a whole lot more readable i.e. prevents errors like perhaps the one you are experiencing now

Comment: this `title aria-    describedby="qtip-5">` ...why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been said in the comments, but really all you need to do is clean up your code.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/4kKL4/)

HTML

```
<form id="search-form" action="/properties/search" method="get">
  <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search for a Website" autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="button" data-hasqtip="5" oldtitle="search">&nbsp;</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#search-form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 9px;
  float: left;
}

#search-form fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: 425px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  border: 1px solid #ced8dd;
}

#search-form input[type="text"] {
  position: relative;
  font-size: .8125em;
  line-height: 1.3846153846153846;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 5px;
  border-width: 0;
  width: 380px;
}


#search-form button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ced8dd;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://images.househappy.org/icon_sprite_1x_v14.png");
  background-position: -10px -22px;
}
```